# Cordova iOS touch scroll not working

Tags: ios, cordova, scroll

I am building a cordova app for both Android and iOS. In android the scroll function is working perfectly fine, but in iOS scrolling down or up seems completely disabled, I've tried adding this into CSS.

```
*{
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

I have also set my viewport

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

I was told to use [iScroll](https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll) as a workaround but it seems if I used such a plugin I would have to apply it to all pages and divs separately. I am trying to enable scrolling for the whole application so this seems like a tedious and inefficient solution.

Any ideas on how to solve this issue, I believe it could have something to do with UIWebkit, I will look into it further.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

According to [https://github.com/twbs/ratchet/issues/138][1]

try to substitute

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

with

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto;
```

If not work, try to set your body style as follows

```
overflow-y: auto;
```